# Update controller scope from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am creating reusable UI components with AngularJS directives. I would like to have a controller that contains my business logic with the nested components (directives). I want the directives to be able to manipulate a single property on the controller scope. The directives need to have an isolate scope because I might use the same directive more than once, and each instance needs to be bound to a particular controller scope property.

So far, the only way I can apply changes back to the controller's scope is to call `scope.$apply()` from the directive. But this breaks when I'm inside of an ng-click callback because of rootScope:inprog (scope operation in progress) errors.

So my **question**: What is the best way to make my controller aware when a child directive has updated a value on the controller's scope?

I've considered having a function on the controller that the directive could call to make an update, but that seems heavy to me.

Here is my code that breaks on an ng-click callback. *Keep in mind that I don't just want to solve the ng-click issue.* I want the best overall solution to apply reusable directives to modify a parent scope/model.

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-directive value="val1"></my-directive>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
...
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.val1 = 'something';
}});
```

**directive**

```
...
.directive('myDirective', [function () {

return {
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.buttonClick = function () {
            var val = 'new value';
            scope.value = val;
            scope.$apply(); 
        };
    },
    scope: {
        value: '='
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="buttonClick()"></button>'
};
}]);
```

Comment: You could emit events on $rootScope.

Comment: @camden_kid I was hoping for better encapsulation. At the very least I'll use the controller method I've considered. I don't think I want to add more chatter on the root scope though.

Comment: You don't need to call $apply(), since the buttonClick function is called by the ng-click directive, and is thus not executed outside of angular's event handling. If you want to modify an attribute, then what you have is fine (except you shouldn't use $apply()). If you want to call a callback function, then pass a callable function using `'&'` instead of `'='`.

Comment: You could inject a service. One thing I've noticed is that you have a button within the directive element markup. It won't work like that. You need a template (or templateURL) in your directive.

Comment: @camden_kid you're right about the template. I posted it this way for brevity, but I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of two-way data binding in directives is exactly what you're asking about -- to "[allow] directives to modify a parent scope/model."

First, double-check that you have set up two-way data binding correctly on the directive attribute which exposes the variable you want to share between scopes. In the controller, you can use `$watch` to detect updates if you need to do something when the value changes. In addition, you have the option of adding an event-handler attribute to the directive. This allows the directive to call a function when something happens. Here's an example:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <my-directive value="val1" on-val-change="myFunc"> <!-- Added on-change binding -->
        <button ng-click="buttonClick()"></button>
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: you pointed me down the right path. My issue was tangled up with two-way bindings and primitives.

Answer (score 4):

I think your question about `$scope.apply` is a red herring. I'm not sure what problem it was solving for you as you evolved this demo and question, but that's not what it's for, and FWIW [your example works for me without it](http://plnkr.co/edit/TYmDqxuqv50QyW6UMZuP?p=preview).

You're not supposed to have to worry about this issue ("make controller aware ... that [something] modified a value on a scope"); Angular's data binding takes care of that automatically.

It is a little complicated here because with the directive, there are multiple scopes to worry about. The outer scope belongs to the `<div ng-controller=myCtrl>`, and that scope has a .val property, and there's an inner scope created by the `<my-directive>` which also has a .val property, and the `buttonClick` handler inside `myDirective` modifies the inner one. But you declared myDirective's scope with `value: '='` which sets up bidirectional syncing of that property value between the inner and outer scope.

So it should work automatically, and in the plunker I created from your question code, it does work automatically.

So where does `scope.$apply` come in? It's explicitly for triggering a digest cycle when Angular doesn't know it needs to. (And if you use it when Angular did know it needed a digest cycle already, you get a nested digest cycle and the "inprog" error you noticed.) [Here's the doc link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), from which I quote "$apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework". You need to use it, for example, when responding to an event handler set up with non-Angular methods -- direct DOM event bindings, jQuery, socket.io, etc. If you're using these mechanisms in an Angular app it's often best to wrap them in a directive or service that handles the Angular-to-non-Angular interface so the rest of your app doesn't have to worry about it.

(`scope.$apply` is actually a wrapper around `scope.$digest` that also manages exception handling. This isn't very clear from the docs. I find it easier to understand the name/behavior of `$digest`, and then consider `$apply` to be "the friendlier version of `$digest` that I'm actually supposed to use".)

One final note on `$apply`; it takes a function callback argument and you're supposed to do the work inside this callback. If you do some work and then call `$apply` with no arguments afterwards, it works, but at that point it's the same as `$digest`. So if you *did* need to use `$apply` here, it should look more like:

`scope.buttonClick = function() {
   scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.value = newValue;
   });
});`